# How to work out length of an IP Packet

Tags: networking, ip, datagram

An IP packet with no options, broken into 3 fragments.

Fragment 1 - offset of 0
Fragment 2 - offset of 358
Fragment 3 - offset of 510 and a total length of 120

How can I calculate how long the original IP packet was?

Comment: There is no such thing as an IP datagram. Do you mean an UDP datagram, or an IP packet? and what is the 'total length' the length of?

Comment: @EJP I have updated the question

Comment: @EJP The RFC calls IP packets "internet datagrams".

Comment: @RonMaupin Indeed, but not 'IP datagrams', and the question was ambiguous.

Comment: @EJP, a layer-2 frame is a datagram, as is a layer-3 packet or a layer-4 segment. An IP packet is a layer-3 datagram. A datagram is just the basic unit for the particular layer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some invalid numbers for fragment offsets since IP must be fragmented on 64-bit boundaries.

When in doubt, refer to the RFC ([RFC 791, INTERNET PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)):

> Fragmentation
>
> Fragmentation of an internet datagram is necessary when it
> originates in a local net that allows a large packet size and must
> traverse a local net that limits packets to a smaller size to reach
> its destination.
>
> An internet datagram can be marked "don't fragment."  Any internet
> datagram so marked is not to be internet fragmented under any
> circumstances.  If internet datagram marked don't fragment cannot be
> delivered to its destination without fragmenting it, it is to be
> discarded instead.
>
> Fragmentation, transmission and reassembly across a local network
> which is invisible to the internet protocol module is called
> intranet fragmentation and may be used [6].
>
> The internet fragmentation and reassembly procedure needs to be able
> to break a datagram into an almost arbitrary number of pieces that
> can be later reassembled.  The receiver of the fragments uses the
> identification field to ensure that fragments of different datagrams
> are not mixed.  The fragment offset field tells the receiver the
> position of a fragment in the original datagram.  The fragment
> offset and length determine the portion of the original datagram
> covered by this fragment.  The more-fragments flag indicates (by
> being reset) the last fragment.  These fields provide sufficient
> information to reassemble datagrams.
>
> The identification field is used to distinguish the fragments of one
> datagram from those of another.  The originating protocol module of
> an internet datagram sets the identification field to a value that
> must be unique for that source-destination pair and protocol for the
> time the datagram will be active in the internet system.  The
> originating protocol module of a complete datagram sets the
> more-fragments flag to zero and the fragment offset to zero.
>
> To fragment a long internet datagram, an internet protocol module
> (for example, in a gateway), creates two new internet datagrams and
> copies the contents of the internet header fields from the long
> datagram into both new internet headers.  The data of the long
> datagram is divided into two portions on a 8 octet (64 bit) boundary
> (the second portion might not be an integral multiple of 8 octets,
> but the first must be).  Call the number of 8 octet blocks in the
> first portion NFB (for Number of Fragment Blocks).  The first
> portion of the data is placed in the first new internet datagram,
> and the total length field is set to the length of the first
> datagram.  The more-fragments flag is set to one.  The second
> portion of the data is placed in the second new internet datagram,
> and the total length field is set to the length of the second
> datagram.  The more-fragments flag carries the same value as the
> long datagram.  The fragment offset field of the second new internet
> datagram is set to the value of that field in the long datagram plus
> NFB.
>
> This procedure can be generalized for an n-way split, rather than
> the two-way split described.
>
> To assemble the fragments of an internet datagram, an internet
> protocol module (for example at a destination host) combines
> internet datagrams that all have the same value for the four fields:
> identification, source, destination, and protocol.  The combination
> is done by placing the data portion of each fragment in the relative
> position indicated by the fragment offset in that fragment's
> internet header.  The first fragment will have the fragment offset
> zero, and the last fragment will have the more-fragments flag reset
> to zero.